# Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation of type ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am attempting to create a many-to-many relationship between a custom class and a class that inherits from IdentityUser where the string key is swapped for a GUID key. The error I get when I try to create a migration is the following:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
> 'AcademyStatistics.Acolyte' of type 'AcademyUser'. Either manually
> configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the
> '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
> 'OnModelCreating'.

Many-to-many mapping table with some extra columns for additional information:

```
public class AcademyStatistics
{
    public AcademyStatistics()
    {
        AcolyteInProgressTrials = new HashSet<Trial>();
        AcolyteCompletedTrials = new HashSet<Trial>();
        TrialTotalAcolytes = new HashSet<AcademyUser>();
    }

    public Guid AcolyteId { get; set; }
    public virtual AcademyUser Acolyte { get; set; } = null!;

    public Guid TrialId { get; set; }
    public virtual Trial Trial { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Trial> AcolyteInProgressTrials { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<Trial> AcolyteCompletedTrials { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<AcademyUser> TrialTotalAcolytes { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

The class that inherits from IdentityUser:

```
public class AcademyUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public AcademyUser()
    {
        AcademyStatistics = new HashSet<AcademyStatistics>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<AcademyStatistics> AcademyStatistics { get; set; }
}
```

The custom class:

```
public class Trial
{
    public Trial()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        AcademyStatistics = new HashSet<AcademyStatistics>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Comment(IdComment)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<AcademyStatistics> AcademyStatistics { get; set; }
}
```

The application works without the many-to-many relationship i.e. I can successfully create a migration in which the autogenerated AspNetUsers table uses a GUID key instead of a string key.

I have also created an EntityConfiguration for the mapping table in which I configure the composite key:

```
public class AcademyStatisticsEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AcademyStatistics>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AcademyStatistics> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(ck => new { ck.AcolyteId, ck.TrialId });
    }
}
```

In addition, here's my custom DbContext class which is configured to work with my custom IdentityUser and to apply all the configurations in the assembly:

```
public class AcademyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AcademyUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
{
    public AcademyDbContext(DbContextOptions<AcademyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    ...
    public DbSet<Trial> Trials { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<AcademyStatistics> AcademiesStatistics { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        Assembly configAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AcademyDbContext)) ??
                                  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(configAssembly);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! I am not 100% sure if my approach is correct so I would appreciate any pointers as to how I can do things differently as well.

Comment: In `AcademyStatistics`, you have two navigations to the custom user entity - `AcademyUser Acolyte` and `ICollection<AcademyUser> TrialTotalAcolytes`. These are **two** relationships. On the other entity `AcademyUser` you have just **one** navigation `ICollection<AcademyStatistics> AcademyStatistics`. So EF Core does not know how to pair the navigations, you need fluent configuration, e.g. `HasOne` + `WithMany` and `HasMany` + `WithMany`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I am still learning the ropes of this technology. I decided to change the functionality of the AcademyStatistics class and I managed to get past the issue I was having. Thank you for your help!